# Django views with nested serializers

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have the following model structure:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Child1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)


class Child2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

With the serializers:

```
class Child1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child1
        fields = (
            "name",
        )


class Child2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child2
        fields = (
            "name",
        )

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child1_ctx = Child1Serializer(many=False, required=False)
    child2_ctx = Child2Serializer(many=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = (
            "name",
            "child1_ctx",
            "child2_ctx"
        )
        read_only_fields = ("name")
```

The ViewSet:

```
class ParentViewSet(GenericViewSet, RetrieveModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin):
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()
```

However, when calling the ParentViewSet I only receive the fields for that model and not a combination of all its related submodels!?

Return value:

```
{
 "name": "test"
}
```

Comment: Is `SocialMediaContextContainer` and `Parent` model are same? or is it a typo?

Comment: Both child field names are unresolvable. Define `source=<reverse_relation_name>`.

Comment: @JPG sorry that was a typo, I updated the code

Comment: @Ivan Where should I define the `source`?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your models something like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Child1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="children1")


class Child2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="children2")
```

Then in serializer you can specify something like this:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    child1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    child2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = (
            "name",
            "child1",
            "child2",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("name")

    def get_child1(self, parent):
        return Child1Serializer(many=True, instance=parent.children1.all()).data

    def get_child2(self, parent):
        return Child2Serializer(many=True, instance=parent.children2.all()).data
```

In child serializer `many=True` because several childs can have foreignkey to parent, so for each parent there maybe more than 1 child. If you want to return only single child, then you can make `many=False` but then make sure you're passing only single child model in instance

Comment: Does this then also work for updates or would I have to override the `update` method?

Comment: Django_rest_framework doesn't support nested update, you'll need to override and provide your custom logic.

Comment: But `parent.child1` will not work since child1 since it's not an instance of that model!?